# How to keep focus on input element when Angular datepicker is opened?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, datepicker

I want to open material datepicker when clicking on input field AND for input field to be focused after that. How can I implement this functionality?

Here what I've comed up with:

```html
<mat-form-field>
  <mat-label>Choose a date</mat-label>
  <input
    #dateInput
    matInput
    [matDatepicker]="picker"
    (focusin)="picker.open()"
  />
  <mat-hint>MM/DD/YYYY</mat-hint>
  <mat-datepicker-toggle matIconSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
  <mat-datepicker
    #picker
    [restoreFocus]="false"
    (closed)="handleClose()"
    (opened)="dateInput.focus()"
  ></mat-datepicker>
</mat-form-field>
```

I tried reacting to `opened` event on datepicker and manually focusing `input` element. But this works only with some delay with `setTimeout` (1ms is enough). I know this approach is ugly and I would like to do this in a nicer way.

Here is the working code and the example of what I'm trying to achieve:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/bpngyv-rfsctv?file=src%2Fexample%2Fdatepicker-overview-example.html